# Airflow docker connection to Snowflake giving "250001: 250001: Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s).Aborting"

Tags: docker, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

I get `250001: 250001: Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s).Aborting` when I try connecting to Snowflake from Airflow in docker. I tried Snowflake Connector for Python Version: 3.1.0 and Snowflake Connector for Python Version: 3.0.4 and got the same error.

```
Error: snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: 250001: 250001: Could not connect to Snowflake backend
```

Error experienced in both 2.6.3
Snowflake Connector for Python Version: 3.0.4, Python Version: 3.7.17, Platform: Linux-5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-debian-11.7

and 2.7.0
Snowflake Connector for Python Version: 3.1.0
Python Version: 3.8.17, Platform: Linux-5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5

It is not a Snowflake incorrect connection details problem as the same information works fine in AWS managed airflow 2.6.3

Installed Airflow 2.6.3 and Airflow 2.7.0 in Docker in Windows. Got the same error in both places.

Comment: Does a `curl -vvv https://<accountname>.snowflakecomputing.com` works from the Docker container?

Comment: No, it does not. In fact for any https I am getting the below error -
(airflow)curl -vvv https://www.google.com
• successfully set certificate verify locations:
• CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
• CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
• TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
• SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
• Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: Are you behind a proxy/firewall? See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58338266/curl-certificate-fail-in-docker-container) post.

Comment: I have found the solution. You can see it here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13671